# How to set the version number of a Vagrant box using a Packer build?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, packer

The version of the box that is added is always `v0`; how can I change this value? For example, when I do a `vagrant box list`, my box is always version `v0`.

I'm creating a VirtualBox Vagrant "box" using Packer, but I can't figure out how to set the version of the box output.

The Packer build command consumes a builder JSON file

```
$ packer build builder.json

...

==> virtualbox-iso (vagrant): Creating Vagrant box for 'virtualbox' provider
    virtualbox-iso (vagrant): Copying from artifact: dist-28/ion-disk001.vmdk
    virtualbox-iso (vagrant): Copying from artifact: dist-28/ion.ovf
    virtualbox-iso (vagrant): Renaming the OVF to box.ovf...
    virtualbox-iso (vagrant): Compressing: Vagrantfile
    virtualbox-iso (vagrant): Compressing: box.ovf
    virtualbox-iso (vagrant): Compressing: ion-disk001.vmdk
    virtualbox-iso (vagrant): Compressing: metadata.json
```

and the output of the Packer step above is Vagrant box called `packer_virtualbox-iso_virtualbox.box`, which I then add to Vagrant using

```
$ vagrant box add BOX_NAME packer_virtualbox-iso_virtualbox.box
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'BOX_NAME' (v0) for provider: 
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file:///packer/packer_virtualbox-iso_virtualbox.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'BOX_NAME' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

I want to change the value `v0` to something else. This is the contents of builder.json

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "vm_name": "ion-${ION_BUILD_NUMBER}",
      "output_directory": "dist-${ION_BUILD_NUMBER}",
      "iso_url": "${ISO_URL}",
      "iso_checksum": "${MD5}",
      ...
    }
  ],
  "post-processors": [
    "vagrant"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was an [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/1143) fixed so you can now provide your own `metadata.json` file

see the content of the [box metadata](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format.html#box-metadata)

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "description": "xxxx",
  "versions": [
    {
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "providers": [
        {
          "name": "virtualbox",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I created my box with packer, so how do I get this metadata inside the box that packer created?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I could use the output filename as a version number

```
  "post-processors": [
    {
      "output": "box/vm-${ION_BUILD_NUMBER}.box",
      "type": "vagrant"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Did you find a better way?

Comment: no, the only way i could figure out how to do it was put the version number in the box build output. lame. it was too painful, and preventing forward progress, so i deal with the worts.